# Section Hierarchy in Hugo

Tags: permalinks, hugo, blogdown, toml

I'm trying to build a structure for permalinks in Hugo + blogdown where a post will have the permalink structure of

**websitename/category/slug**

Not sure how to do this because I've set the config.toml permalink structure to

```
    [permalinks] 
        posts = "/:section/:slug"
```

and I place the post (an .md file) into a folder, which is a category, underneath the posts file but I get a url similar to **websitename/posts/category/slug**... when what I really want is **websitename/category/slug**.

I was hoping to make the category the section, but not have "post" in the URL.

I'm still trying to figure out where to place the _index.md file but have not been very successful. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does this have to do with the R programming language? ([tag:r] tag)

Comment: Could you post your website repo? which theme are you using?

Comment: Hi. I'm using beautiful hugo, not sure if i Could post the website repo because it's not being served by anything like Github pages or netlify

Comment: @r2evans it was made using blogdown, so I thought others who had experience with the package could chime in

Answer (score 2):

The permalink is set on a `per section` basis. The sections are the first-level directories under `content`, not under `content/posts/`.

So, if you want the permalink to be `websitename/category/slug`, arrange category directories(or `sections` by the Hugo term) like this:

```
content
├── category1
│   └── 2015-01-04-first-post.md
├── category2
│   └── 2015-01-27-dear-diary.md
├── _index.md
├── page
│   └── about.md
└── post
    ├── 2017-03-07-bigimg-sample.md
    └── 2017-03-20-photoswipe-gallery-sample.md
```

and set

```
[permalinks] 
    category1 = "/:section/:slug"
    category2 = "/:section/:slug"
    page = "/:section/:slug"
    post = "/:section/:slug"
```

in your config.yaml

Source: https://gohugo.io/content-management/urls/#permalinks

Comment: Thank you! This looks *exactly* like what I was looking for. Will report back on my experience.

Comment: @dailyzad How did it go?